# Почему нет валидации в Angular 7?

Tags: валидация, angular

Создаю форму в ангуляре, делаю валидацию примерно так

```
<input name="Name" #Name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.Name" 
        class="form-control" placeholder="Mission naming" required maxlength="100">
```

Насколько я понимаю, после валидации в инпуте должны быть `ng-invalid` и `ng-touched` , но их нет, после компиляции код инпута такой

```
<input class="form-control" maxlength="100" name="Name" required="" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-maxlength="100">
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: ваше понимание неправильное, `ng-touched` тут даже по названию можно понять, что этот класс добавится только после взаимодействия с инпутом, а не после компиляции

Comment: @overthesanity прошу прощения, имелось ввиду, что после компиляции при взаимодействии его нет

Comment: сделайте пожалуйста  [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)